# Альтернативный доступ к ресурсу C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources

Есть следующий код записи ресурса на диск:

```
        using (var fstream = File.Create("test.dll"))
        {
            byte[] buf = Properties.Resources.test;
            fstream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }
```

И он работает, но доступ к ресурсу получается так: `Properties.Resources.test`. Есть ли альтернативный способ получить доступ к ресурсу? Допустим записав в строку `"Properties.Resources.test"` или что-то на подобии этого, не используя `.`?

Comment: @Bulson `'Resources" является тип, который недопустим в данном контексте.`

Comment: А в чём проблема, у вас же кодогенерация?

Comment: а так вообще наверняка покатит `Properties.Resources["test"]`

Comment: @VladD я уже пробовала так делать, выше ошибку написала. Уже за столько времени не нашла ответа, так что  отказалась от этой идеи.

Comment: Эээ, ну так выясните, почему ошибка. Вы ж генерируете код? Сбросьте код в файл, откройте Студией, исправьте. Менять всё тупо из-за синтаксической ошибки как-то не выглядит хорошей идеей.